# Take a Chance VS Grab a Chance

Tags: meaning, idioms

When I looked for the meaning of "take a chance", it seems like 
it involves risks.

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/take-a-chance) says:

> to do something even though it involves risk

So I think it's similar to take a risk.

Then how about "get/have a chance" and "grab/seize a chance"?

Do they also involves the nuance of risks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chance can have the implication of risk (of loss), but not always.  On its face, the word chance simply means that a result could fail, not necessarily that there are negative consequences for failure.  There often are negative consequences for failure, of course, but based on context *and idiom* the listener should be able to determine whether risk is involved.

Idiomatically, "take a chance" definitely has the implication that failure will have consequences.  Idiomatically, "get a chance" does not have this implication, nor "grab/seize a chance".  This may help you to remember: people typically *want* to "get" things.  "Getting" things is nice!  But you can "take" anything, including things you don't necessarily want.  On the same note, while you can "take" anything, you *typically* won't "grab" or "seize" things you didn't intend to.

As a side note and background for how these idioms are used, a person will typically first hear "get a chance *{to do something}*" as a small child, where failure is definitely a possibility (because you are a small child without much skill) but consequences are minor (because you are a small child protected by adults).  "Get a chance to kick the ball" for instance.

Regardless of why an idiom carries an implication-- without a negative consequence for failure, the word "chance" becomes very nearly synonymous with "opportunity".  In fact, you can substitute "get an opportunity" for "get a chance" in nearly all instances of the phrase without changing the meaning.  Likewise, "grab/seize an opportunity" for "grab/seize a chance".